# line with block and histbase

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

On this script

```
maType = input.string(title='EMA ou HMA', defval='EMA', options=['EMA', 'HMA'])
len = input(title='EMA 200', defval=200)
src = input(title='Source', defval=close)
ma(type, src, len) =>
    float result = 0
    if type == 'EMA'  // Exponential
        result := ta.ema(src, len)
        result
    if type == 'HMA'  // Hull
        result := ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(src, len / 2) - ta.wma(src, len), math.round(math.sqrt(len)))
        result
    result
emaHigh = ma(maType, high, len)
emaLow = ma(maType, low, len)
BBMC = ma(maType, close, len)
useTrueRange = input(true)
multy = input.float(0.2, step=0.05, title='Base Channel Multiplier')
Keltma = ma(maType, src, len)
range_1 = useTrueRange ? ta.tr : high - low
rangema = ta.ema(range_1, len)
upperk = Keltma + rangema * multy
lowerk = Keltma - rangema * multy
    Hlv = int(na)
Hlv := close > emaHigh ? 1 : close < emaLow ? -1 : Hlv[1]
sslDown = Hlv < 0 ? emaHigh : emaLow
color_bar = close > upperk ? #00c3ff : close < lowerk ? #ff0062 : color.gray
color_ssl1 = close > sslDown ? #00c3ff : close < sslDown ? #ff0062 : na
p1 = plot(show_EMA_200 ? BBMC : na, color=color_bar, linewidth=1, title='EMA 200')
```

I want to change the plot to a line with "block"

So i try with this.

```
plot(BBMC, style=plot.style_columns, histbase=0, color=color_bar, linewidth=1, title='EMA 200')
```

The "base is :

```
plot(10, style=plot.style_columns, histbase=0, color=color_bar, linewidth=1, title='EMA 200')
```

But don't work because i need to add BBMC.

How can i do this please ?

Thanks

Comment: "Don't work" does not really help us. What exactly is it that does not work? What do you expect and what do you get? I'm not even sure what you mean by "block".

Answer (score 0):

I want to create a think like this.

One line EMA, one line HMA, .... and look like this

[image]

Don't work because if I put BBMC I have a column but I would like it to always be the same height.
So when trying with 10 and histbase, nothing appears. This seems logical since BBMC is not mentioned.

Comment: You should edit your original question if you need to provide further explanation. Only answer if you trying to provide a solution.